# kendo ui angular js grid ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, grid, kendo-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I m trying to use Kendo grid in my angular js app. I m creating a directive so I can use it in different tables among the application. Once the ng-repeat renders the dom I want to call: 
  element.kendogrid().
Since there is no post-render callback for ng-repeat, some people suggest using two directives:
1-

angular.module('app')

```
.directive('rowDirective', function () {
    return function(scope, element){
        if (scope.$last){
            scope.$emit('LastElementMessage');
        }
    };
});
```

2-

angular.module('app')

```
.directive('tableDirective', function () {
    return function(scope, element){
        scope.$on('LastElementMessage', function(event){
            $(element).kendoGrid({
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This approach works fine and everything is executed in the order it should. The ng-repeat works fine by it self, which means it renders the items in the right order but when I use the kendo-grid, it renders this: {{customer.CustomerID}} inside the grid. Has anyone gone through something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps you should take a look at Angular Kendo UI project at http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/ - it does rather good job of "marrying" Kendo UI with AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

See http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular.

There are specific custom directives that enable kendo ui to play nicely with angular js. E.G. ***k-data-source, k-columns, k-selectable, k-pageable***.  These should be included in the latest version of kendo ui. Just make sure to include "kendo.directives" as a dependency on your top level-module :

```
var MyModule = angular.module('MyModule', ["ngRoute", "kendo.directives"]);
```